# What do these arrows mean?

Tags: guitar, notation, sheet-music, classical-guitar, j-s-bach

I've noticed on Edson Lopes pieces he highlights (I think) certain phrases. Not sure what he is trying to tell us when he puts a section between these arrows. Notice arrow pointing left and down, then right and down.  I never ran into these arrows before. Here's an example from his transcription of Bach's Toccata and Fugue in D minor, BWV 565.

[image: Edson Lopes transcription mm. 16-23]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what piece this is. Being able to listen to it or look at an original score (this is a Bach transcription, yes?) might be illuminating.

Comment: [Youtube of Edson Lopes playing Toccata and Fugue, BWV 565 (J. S. Bach) at 01:29, matches above](https://youtu.be/SYHAA-gP6o4?t=89)

Comment: @OwainEvans to the rescue!

Comment: @Aaron Just lucky [Edson Lopes has a youTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwVcJ7gSCsXHE_aSQeZkqEg) and [an IMSPL page with scores](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Lopes%2C_Edson) but even just the D minor to E minor transposition (and for guitar) does make the so popular piece much less recognisable.

Comment: @OwainEvans you aren't one of us Otters are you?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No. I can READ! But in all seriousness, I'd put bar 19 32nds and bar 21 32nds down stem and just get rid of those rests to make it more readable.

Comment: @OwainEvans "Otter" is an obscure reference to a bunch of xkcd fans. Did not mean to offend

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for explaining, I genuinely didn't know. No offence taken. Ah. Click. I think I get, the cartoon stuff. Not a fan, but can appreciate the art form and that it can REALLY be misunderstood / be offensive so not everyones cup-of-tea

Answer (score 1):

Based on their placement in the score, they appear to mark phrase boundaries. Note that they come in pairs: e.g., m. 18 has a leftward mark and m. 19 has a rightward mark. Similarly mm. 21-22.

As @OldBrixtonian points out, these marked passages are played like cadenzas, with some rhythmic freedom, which can be heard in this recording (thanks to @OwainEvans):

Comment: I'd love to hear this on a guitar! It looks to me as if the arrows surround *libero*, cadenza-like passages. I'm surprised there's no footnote explaining them.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Agreed about the candenzas. Hopefully the OP posts an original. I left that out of my answer until there was a way to confirm.

Comment: You mean the original organ version? Yes, some edition might mark those passages. I don't think Bach would have done. Maybe a guitarist will show up and tell us what they are.

Comment: Thanks for granting my wish :-) I thought you KNEW what the piece was BTW.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I confess to being a bit chagrined at not recognizing it immediately. Owain Evans found the YouTube vid.

Comment: Lovely word! I haven't been properly chagrined for *years*. It's gone a bit quiet round here, hasn't it? Too many cowboys and not enough rainbow nation peoples. I wonder why.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Perhaps people are too chagrined to show up. :-) Truthfully, I was considering bringing up the seeming lack of traffic on chat, but I'm still pretty new, so I don't really have a feel for what a normal pace is.

Comment: :-) Maybe they are. Maybe it's the prospect of another lockdown. I've only been here a year (this week, I think) but I've never seen it so quiet. I get a bit lost when I find I've somehow wandered into chat or meta. But yes, it'd be interesting to know what the old lags say. I did see some discussion in one place or the other, about relaxing the rules a little to allow people to ask questions like "Isn't THIS interesting?" Something like that might help.